# Twitter OAuth API how to post to someone else's twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm now dealing with twitter API and my app posts some text to twitter. I managed to get acces to my twitter and i can post now to my twitter using ma app's consumer key and consuer secret, also using my access key and access token for authenticate me. But how do I post messages to someone else's twitter knowing only his password and login? Do I need somehow to get his access key and access token? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

previously it was possible to post Tweet remotely using username and password. This can not be done anymore.

All methods of status update using curl / json are deprecated and not functioning.

Twitter requires you to use OAuth 100% of the time now.